# How to determine the increment term of normal and shear stress in infinitesimal cube ?

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor, equilibrium, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

Consider a solid body, if it is in equilibrium then every infinitesimal part of the body is in equilibrium so i take an infinitesimal cube with side lengths, $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$ and try to write the equilibrium equations in all three directions. What i don't understand is, where the increment terms for example  $$\frac{\partial  \sigma_{xx}}{\partial x}dx$$ come from? why they have first order differential form ? [image]

Comment: They have 1st order differential form because they are 1st order rates of change in the relevent directions. The same forms appear if you are considering changes across a cube for any kind of scalar field, eg electric potential, temperature, density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terms such as $\left(\frac{\partial\sigma_{xx}}{\partial x}\right)dx$ are used to accommodate the fact that stresses change over distance in the beam. If you didn't permit this change, then every part of the beam would exhibit identical loads, identical shear, identical bending moment, identical curvature, etc., which of course isn't realistic or useful in a theory of elasticity.

Now, we know that these parameters all generally change nonlinearly in the cross section and along the length of the beam. In an infinitesimal element, however, it's sufficient to approximate the change as linear over its short length. The slope or gradient in the property is then $\frac{\partial\sigma_{xx}}{\partial x}$, the distance is $dx$, and the corresponding change is $\left(\frac{\partial\sigma_{xx}}{\partial x}\right)dx$.

The same mechanism is used to develop differential equations in all aspects of physics. In heat transfer, for example, we might have a heat flux $Q$ entering the beam from the left. If we made the heat flux leaving the beam from the right be $Q$ as well, then we couldn't model much beyond uniform, constant-temperature beams, which again is not realistic or useful. Instead, let's let the right-side heat flux be $Q+\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\right)dx$. In other words, maybe some energy is radiated laterally, or maybe some heat is generated internally, thus altering the axial flow of heat. Now we have the possibility of location-dependent flux, location-dependent temperature, and so on. Same principle.

Note, however, that in each case, equilibrium must be maintained. In the heat transfer case, energy can't be created or destroyed. In the elasticity case, the infinitesimal element can't begin to translate or rotate. All of the $\left(\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial x_i}\right)dx_i$ terms must combine in conjunction with all surface and body forces so that the sum of forces in and moments around every direction is zero. Otherwise you've entered the realm of dynamics.